# Syntax Issue with sql statements

Tags: php, sql

I created a function and it does not work. After staring at it for 15 minutes trying it different ways, I can't get it to work. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my syntax? The variable `$user_id` is a number and `$input` is a string. I'm aware that mysql is deprecated and it is something I'm working on. I just want to know what is wrong with the sql, because after all it is a sql issue.

```
function insert_what_i_do( $user_id, $input) 
{
    if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `profile` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"), 0) !== 1) 
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `profile` (user_id, what_i_do) VALUES ($user_id, '$input')");    
    } 
    else 
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `profile` SET `what_i_do` = '$input' WHERE `user_id` =  $user_id");
    }
};
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: When you say *not working* what do you mean? Any errors?

Comment: So what is the error that you're getting? Is it the SELECT, the INSERT, or the UPDATE?

Comment: Aware of the mysql deprecation. I'm not receiving an error.

Comment: It's not inserting the `$input` into the database.

Comment: You still didn't added quotes around `$input` on last query ..

Comment: What is the value of `$user_id`? The problem is probably that you are checking that `user_id !== 1`. It would be better to check that the *row count* of your query is `0`.

Comment: Did you try to see if `$input` is actually getting to the query? On which query it stops? It doesn't update or it doesn't insert .. or both? try to see what outputs if you don't run `mysql_query` replace it with `echo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is with plain `MySQL`, please take a good look on what I did there, and it's not advisable to use `mysql_*` function anymore as they are deprecated. Note the quoted `$input` ?

```
<?php
    function insert_what_i_do( $user_id, $input) {
        $input = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `profile` WHERE `user_id` = '".(int)$user_id."'");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($num) {
            $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `profile` SET `what_i_do` = '".$input."' WHERE `user_id` =  '".(int)$user_id."'");
        } else {
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `profile` (`user_id`, `what_i_do`) VALUES ('".(int)$user_id."', '".$input."')");
        }
    }
?>
```

You need to learn to use PDO:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    function insert_what_i_do( $user_id, $input) {
        global $db;
        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `profile` WHERE `user_id` = :user_id");
        $stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id));
        $num = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($num) {
            $stmt = $db->query("UPDATE `profile` SET `what_i_do` = :input WHERE `user_id` = :user_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id, ':input' => $input));
        } else {
            $stmt = $db->query("INSERT INTO `profile` (`user_id`, `what_i_do`) VALUES (:user_id, :input)");
            $stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id, ':input' => $input));
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm aware of `real_escape_string` issue and plan on fixing that with prepared statements and parameterized queries with mysqli. I just want to find out what is wrong with the sql code first.

Answer (score 3):

After resolving the PHP issues, note that what you are currently trying to do in 3 mysql queries/statements, can be done in one - assuming that `user_id` is the primary or a unique key:

```
INSERT INTO profile 
  (user_id, what_i_do) 
VALUES 
  ('$user_id', '$input')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  what_i_do = VALUES(what_i_do) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed the single quotes in the update query for `$input`:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `profile` SET `what_i_do` = '$input' WHERE `user_id` =  $user_id");
```

But I also can't see anywhere that you *make* the mysql connection.

Comment: Mysql connection is made elsewhere. I've narrowed the issue down to the function. Also, with the single quotes added it still does not work.